# Multiple SQL WHERE clauses in one table with lots of records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Recently I was asked to develop an app, which basically is going to use 1 main single table in the whole database for the operations.

It has to have around 20 columns with various types - decimals, int, varchar, date, float. At some point the table will have thousands of rows (3-5k).

The app must have the ability to SELECT records by combining each of the columns criteria - e.g. BETWEEN dates, greater than something, smaller than something, equal to something etc. Basically combining a lot of where clauses in order to see the desired result.

So my question is, since I know how to combine the wheres and make the app, what is the best approach? I mean is MySQL good enough not to slow down when I have 3k records and make a SELECT query with 15 WHERE clauses? I've never worked with a database larger than 1k records, so I'm not sure if I should use MySQL for this. Also I'm going to use PHP as a server language if that matters at all.

Comment: Doesn't facebook use MySql? I'm sure that has more than 3k records..

Comment: facebook also has about 100,000 mySQL servers load balanced with memcache integrated and they still complain about performance.... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are talking about conditions in ONE where clause.

3000 rows is very minimal for a relational database.  these typically go far larger (like 3 million+ or even much more)

i am concerned that you have 20 columns in one table.  this sounds like a normalization problem.

Comment: Well, even a perfectly normalized table in the third form may have plenty of rows in some use cases.

Comment: You are correct (I meant conditions), but how do I determine which columns have to be indexed? Generally I know that a column which is used in WHERE clause should be indexed, but that's not efficient every time. Since I could have combinations between all the columns in the table in my where clause, I guess I should have a lot of indexed columns.

Comment: maybe begin another question with your proposed table design - and ask for normalization help...

Answer (score 1):

With a well-defined structure for your database, including appropriate indexes, 3k records is nothing, even with 15 conditions. Even without indexes, it is doubtful that with so few records, you will see any performance hit.

I would however plan for the future and perhaps look at your queries and see if there is any table optimisation you can do at this stage, to save pain in the future. Who knows, 3k records today, 30m next year.

Answer (score 0):

3000 Records in a database is nothing. You won't have any performance issues even with your 15 `WHERE`.
`MySQL` and `PHP` will do the job just fine.

I'd be more concerned about your huge amount of columns. Maybe you should take a look at [this article](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm) to make sure you respect the databases `normal forms`,

Good luck for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think querying a single table of 3-5K rows is going to be particularly intensive. MySQL should be able to cope with something like this easily enough. You could add lot's of indexes to speed up your selects if this is the "choke point" but this will slow down insert, edit's, etc. also if you querying lots of different rows this isn't prob a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As seeing the no of rows is very minimal,I guess it should not cause any performance issue.Still you can look at using OR operator carefully and also indexes on the columns in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Indices, indices, indices!

If you need to check a lot of different columns try flatten your used logic. In any case make sure you have set an appropriate index on the checked columns. A not an index per columns, but one index over all those columns, that a used regularly.